# Jquery / Handlebars.js populate select field from json array

Tags: jquery, json, handlebars.js

I need, based on the json array "option" to populate an select field

My Script look like this:

```
var option =  [
    {"mod":"A","values":
        {"Field":"A","Value":"101"}
    },
    {"mod":"B","values:
        {"Field":"B","Value":"102"}},
    {"mod":"C","values"
        {"Field":"C","Value":"99"}
    },
    {"mod":"D","values":    
        {"Field":"D","Value":"96"}
    }];


var theTemplateScript = $('#shoe-template').html(); 
var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript); 
$('.shoesNav').append(theTemplate(option));
```

and my html is as follow:

```
<script id="shoe-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each option}}
        <option value="{{values.Value}}">
           {{values.Field}}
        </option>
    {{/each}}

</script>
<select class="shoesNav">        
</select>
```

I don't have any console error, however the field is not being populated, what am I missing ?

[JSFiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cu7n6j95/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to namespace the data object with the key in the `{{#each option}}` loop, which in this case is `option`. Here's a working implementation:

```js
var namespace = 'option';
var data = {};

data[namespace] = [{
    "mod": "A",
    "values": {
        "Field": "A",
        "Value": "101"
    }
}, {
    "mod": "B",
    "values": {
        "Field": "B",
        "Value": "102"
    }
}, {
    "mod": "C",
    "values": {
        "Field": "C",
        "Value": "99"
    }
}, {
    "mod": "D",
    "values": {
        "Field": "D",
        "Value": "96"
    }
}];

var theTemplateScript = $('#shoe-template').html();
var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
$('.shoesNav').append(theTemplate(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
<script id="shoe-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each option}}
    <option value="{{values.Value}}">
        {{values.Field}}
    </option>
    {{/each}}
</script>
<select class="shoesNav">
</select>
```

I also updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cu7n6j95/3/

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. is there a way to return the namespace? in this case option

Comment: You're welcome :)
I don't understand your question, could you please elaborate?

Comment: You see I have a big json array with data formated in that way, and I have to loop trough it. the namespace option is dynamically set based on ajax response.

Comment: You would have to create another object and assign it to that namespace. I updated my post to reflect that.